# How do I create a random movement of my sprite in the confines of the screen in Swift?

Tags: xcode, swift

I have this circle that goes up and down the screen and I would like to randomize the movements so its not the same thing over and over. Like for example the circle would go up a few points and then go all the way down and back up really quickly. Something that would be different everytime the user plays the game. This is what I have now:

```
func addCircle() {

    circle.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2, self.size.height / 2.0)
    circle.zPosition = 32
    circle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 75)
    circle.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    circle.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = CircleCategory
    circle.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = HeroCategory
    circle.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = CircleCategory



    let moveDown = SKAction.moveToY(-circle.frame.size.height + 220, duration: 2.5)
    let moveUp = SKAction.moveToY(700, duration: 2.5)
    let sequenceUpAndDown = SKAction.sequence([moveDown, moveUp])
    let repeatSequence = SKAction.repeatActionForever(sequenceUpAndDown)
    circle.runAction(repeatSequence)
    addChild(circle)

}
```

Comment: Maybe is better use gameplaykit ->  GKBehavior with setWeight(1.0, forGoal: GKGoal(toWander: targetSpeed))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    let circle = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.redColor(), size: CGSizeMake(10, 10))

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        circle.position.x = self.size.width/2
        circle.position.y = self.size.height/2 
        addChild(circle)

        func random(min min: CGFloat, max: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
            assert(min < max)
            return CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / 0xFFFFFFFF) * (max - min) + min
        }


        let y1 = random(
            min: circle.size.height/2,
            max: self.size.height - circle.size.height/2
        )

        let y2 = random(
            min: circle.size.height/2,
            max: self.size.height - circle.size.height/2
        )

        let moveDown = SKAction.moveToY(y1, duration: 2.5)
        let moveUp = SKAction.moveToY(y2, duration: 2.5)

        let sequence = SKAction.sequence([moveDown, moveUp])

        circle.runAction(sequence)
    }
}
```

give it a shot

Comment: It works but sometimes the circle just stops and doesn't move. How would I fix that?

Comment: you need to do runActionForever instead of just runAction

Comment: Okay that worked. It goes really slow sometimes also even when I change the duration to 1.0. Is there a way I could make it go faster up and down?

Comment: it might go slower or faster because youre saying that it has to arrive at its destination in a set amount of time.   if it has to travel 100px in 1 second its going to be slower than going 10px in 1 second.  you'll have to work out a variable time that works for you based on the distance that its traveling.